# performance testing of a html website using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Can i do performance testing of a website which is developed only in html. It does not contain any back end. it is made only of html but it contains many pages.

Comment: With JMeter you can do whatever requests you want, so yes, you can create a bunch of requests and execute them with JMeter doing several loops to measure the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

For that purpose you need [Jmeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf). With help of it you can record your interaction with web-site and then filter out some objects (images for example) which you don't need to record/capture.

As a result you'll have a Jmeter script which you can then modify and extend.

You can also read a good tutorial about using Test Script Recorder [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jmeter-to-record-test-scenarios).